# C# Datatable LINQ dynamic row.field<datatype> coded needed

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, datatable

I have the following code. Data is coming from an mysql server. I used the dataadapater.Fill(datatable) object and method to create the datatable CDMAData. The column.datatype is different each time the data range is different. I need to be able to specify datatype dynamically. Is it possible? The error is occuring at r.Field<**int**>.

```
var CarrierCDMAPreResults = from row in CDMAData.AsEnumerable()
    where Dates.Contains(row.Field<DateTime>("DateTime"))
        group row by new { Cascade = row.Field<string>("Cascade"), Sector = row.Field<byte>("Sector"), Carrier = row.Field<byte>("Carrier") } into grp
    select new
    {
        Cascade = grp.Key.Cascade,
        Sector = grp.Key.Sector,                                            
        Carrier = grp.Key.Carrier,
        Attempts = grp.Sum(r => r.Field <int> ("Attempts")),
        Successes = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Successes")),
        Blocks = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Blocks")),
        Drops = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Drops")),
        CDMAPE = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("CDMA Primary Erlang"))
    };
```

Comment: What do you mean you want to specify the datatype dynamically? The datatype will always be the same as the result of your sql query.

Comment: The table returns different datatype for the same column depending on the data. It can be uint32, int32, uint64, int64

Comment: Are you using the same code to process the result set of different queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well a very simple answer to your problem will be to just use Int64 for everything. As all your lower values will still work.

However if your columns start becoming decimals and strings then you will have problems.

```
var CarrierCDMAPreResults = from row in CDMAData.AsEnumerable()
    where Dates.Contains(row.Field<DateTime>("DateTime"))
        group row by new { Cascade = row.Field<string>("Cascade"), Sector = row.Field<byte>("Sector"), Carrier = row.Field<byte>("Carrier") } into grp
    select new
    {
        Cascade = grp.Key.Cascade,
        Sector = grp.Key.Sector,                                            
        Carrier = grp.Key.Carrier,
        Attempts = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<Int64> ("Attempts")),
        Successes = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<Int64>("Successes")),
        Blocks = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<Int64>("Blocks")),
        Drops = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<Int64>("Drops")),
        CDMAPE = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("CDMA Primary Erlang"))
    };
```

Comment: Thank you I ended up insure that table columns are singed by changing the query and casting singed. Then I used long(Int64). It is working.